# Python import class

Tags: python, python-import

In a folder with an empty `__init__.py` file I have a class `Memory` and a class `Worker`. For some reason, I cannot do

```
import Memory
```

nor with the filename

```
import memory
```

and variants don't work, just trying to instantiate wont work either.

```
mem = Memory()
```

gives an error. How do I do proper import?

Comment: You say `__init__.py` is empty, where are these classes defined? And where are you trying to import them into?

Comment: `import folder.Memory`, also define them in the `__init__.py`, it's not there to be empty

Comment: You don't have a class in the folder though, you have a module file. What's the file called and what are its contents?

Comment: @Frontear actually it is perfectly fine for `__init__.py` to be empty. It is there to tell python that the files within that directory are part of a module.  Alot of packages leave the `__init__.py` empty.

Comment: You can't have a class in a folder because a class cannot be represented by a file in Python. Python files always correspond to modules.

Answer (score 0):

`from folder.file import Memory, Worker`

where file is a python file where class is made

i.e

```
folder/
        file.py
```